# How to check Collision detection for GameObjects of same prefab (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision, prefab

(For 2D Project)
I created a gameObject and made it a prefab.
Now when the game starts, the prefab is used to instantiate gameObjects and they all should check if they collide with one another.

I tried other unity's collision methods but it didn't work.
They either kept colliding with themselves (their own rigidbody) or it didn't work at all.

I'm new to unity and learning things. I searched every where but didn't get my question solved. I'll appreciate any help, Thank you!

Prefab is loaded and Instantiated as such..

```
GameObject tile = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Tile") as GameObject);
```

Its a basic gameObject having SpriteRenderer 2D.

I used Box Collider 2D and Rigidbody 2D components on that prefab -
[Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1YUR.png)

A simple script which has **OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)** function to check if it collides..

```
using UnityEngine;  
  
public class TileCollider : MonoBehaviour {  
  
    public Rigidbody2D triggerBody;  

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {  
        if (triggerBody == null)  
            return;  
        if (other.attachedRigidbody == triggerBody) {  
            Debug.Log("Collision!");  
        }  
    }  
  
}
```

I tried it without any if statements - It triggers collision for the Rigidbody2D of the gameObject (itself)

I passed the Prefab itself to check the collision for - [Script in Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP1Cj.png).
This is where were things get bad. It looks for the rigidbody of its own gameObject but I wanted it to search for other cloned gameObjects from same prefab.

Comment: How do you have the prefabs built, where are the colliders, what are your collider and rigidbody settings, and how are you trying to detect collisions?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning before. I was expecting a direct solution to how collision detection works for gameObjects of same prefab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to look at to solve the problem is to check if your prefabs have tags attached to them.

Comment: It worked for other projects but this time I was actually instantiating on a huge collider of other gameObject causing it to trigger at the very beginning. I totally missed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the TileCollider script attached on your prefab which it looks like it is in the inspector, you are checking if the other.attachedRigidbody is its own rigid body (triggerBody). And an object cannot collide with itself. You should probably check if its own rigid body is not the other.attachedRigidbody. If its not its own rigidbody then you have collision with another GameObject!

I hope I understood your question correctly, Thanks!

Comment: Yes! That is what I meant but Sorry it still didn't work anyhow I used Tags and it was solved. The point where I got confused with the gameObject triggering to its own rigidbody was silly. Prefab was Instantiating gameObjects on a collider of other object which had huge scale and I misunderstood. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There looks to be quite a few errors with your code. First, you've got a `triggerBody` but it doesn't look like it's assigned. Hopefully you're assigning this manually as part of the prefab arrangement, but you could guarantee this by doing that hookup in `Start` and throwing an error if it fails to get the Rigidbody, like:

```
public Rigidbody2D triggerBody;  
void Start()
{
    if(triggerBody == null) // Would happen if it's not set in the prefab
    {
        triggerBody = gameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();
    }
    if(triggerBody == null) // Would happen if there is no Rigidbody2D attached at all!
    {
        Debug.LogErrorFormat("Failed to find a Rigidbody2D to use with {0}!", gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

Another issue is that you're asking for *collisions*, but your code is looking for *triggers*. [Here's a link to an article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/oncollisionenter-vs-ontriggerenter-and-when-to-use-them-c62d2ceabcbd), but the short version is that if you're checking `OnTriggerEnter` then at least one of the colliders involved needs to have the `IsTrigger` option ticked:

[image]

Another issue is that you're bailing on the operation if the `triggerBody` is null. As I mentioned at the start, you're not explicitly setting the `triggerBody` in your code, so if it's also not set in the prefab then you'd abort here even if the collider options were set correctly.

Finally, and probably most importantly, is this snippet doesn't make sense:

```
if (other.attachedRigidbody == triggerBody) {  
    Debug.Log("Collision!");  
}
```

What you're saying here is that you want there to be a collision if the other rigidbody is the same as the local rigidbody. This would ensure the behavior you described in your post,

> They either kept colliding with themselves (their own rigidbody) or it didn't work at all.

You're only calling it a collision if they're colliding with themselves! The way to check if it's NOT self-colliding is to make sure the `other.attachedRigidbody` is NOT equal to the local `triggerBody`!

What you would want instead would be:

```
if (other.attachedRigidbody != triggerBody) {  
    Debug.Log("Collision!");  
}
```

Comment: 1) There's no issue with the `triggerBody` not being initialized - I set its value in the inspector  
  
2) I'm sorry for using the word _collision_ where I meant they **touch** each other. And yes I ticked the `isTrigger` option  
  
3) In the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function, I messed up.  
  
Thank you for your time it helped me even more in other mistakes. The solution was to use Tags to separate clones and rigidbody2d I passed to the prefab as the `triggerBody`.